# Conditional filtering with join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a query similar in nature to the following in a stored procedure that has a single parameter:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    DepartmentID,
    FileName
FROM
    Document
-- conditional join from here
JOIN
    AllowedDepartmentList ON DepartmentID = AllowedDepartmentList.ID 
                          AND @IsAdmin = 'false'
```

The parameter is `@IsAdmin` with the data type bit.

The two tables I work with is the `Document` table (see structure in query above), and the `AllowedDepartmentList` that contains a single `int` column.

I use this query to filter the returned results of the `Document` table with join. I do not use the `WHERE DepartmentID IN()` clause, because the AllowedDepartmentList can be as long as 600-700 items (too much for `IN()` to handle with good performance in a potentially 1M record table)
So I filter using a join, but the filtering should only execute, if the @IsAdmin parameter is `false`. Like the lines after the *-- conditional join from here* comment weren't even there.

I tried the query above but it produces no records. I suspect I'm using the wrong type of join, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a left join in combination of a where that either requires admin privileges, or a match on the join

```
SELECT
    ID,
    DepartmentID,
    FileName
FROM
    Document
-- conditional join from here
LEFT JOIN
    AllowedDepartmentList ON DepartmentID = AllowedDepartmentList.ID 
WHERE
    @IsAdmin = 'true' OR AllowedDepartmentList.ID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Note, that jhilden's suggestion is more efficient, since you'd save yourself from a join in the situations where it's not needed. I do, however, understand your argument of keeping just one query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be OK, I gotta test it. And yes, you're right, we also have to test if the extra joins cause so much overhead that it's worth duplicating the code.

Comment: I accepted your answer as we have implemented this solution for testing purposes. It works as needed and gets the job done, but performance should be measured. There are many other answers that fit the bill, so thanks for everyone who took the time to fiddle with my problem.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, put your parameters into WHERE clauses VS joins.  A somewhat simple solution would be to have a TVF or sproc that runs two completely different queries.  something like this:

```
IF (@isAdmin = 0) --notice I used a SQL bool vs a string of 'false'
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ID,
        DepartmentID,
        FileName
    FROM
        Document
    JOIN
        AllowedDepartmentList ON DepartmentID = AllowedDepartmentList.ID;
END;
ELSE
   --@IsAdmin is not false, so don't join
    SELECT
        ID,
        DepartmentID,
        FileName
    FROM
        Document;
END;
```

Comment: This is what I tried to avoid: duplicating the select. The exact select in our SP is a lot more complicated (like 150 rows) and gets very ugly if the whole shebang is duplicated... not to mention future modifications.

Comment: @Daniel If the whole shebang is 150 rows all the more reason to have an efficient query.  How hard can a copy paste and remove a join be?

Comment: You're absolutely right in this matter. We will have to do some stress test on real data to figure the best answer. I was merely looking for an alternative to code duplication, but I never expected to get so many good suggestions (including staying on the current track, just as jhilden - and you - suggested).

Answer (score 3):

you can use exists condition, like this:

```
SELECT
 ID,
 DepartmentID,
 FileName
FROM Document
WHERE exists(
 SELECT 1 from AllowedDepartmentList 
 WHERE DepartmentID = AllowedDepartmentList.ID) 
OR @IsAdmin = 'true'
```

Comment: I'm think it is faster, especially if you use additional conditions, but you must try. join is to get data, exist is perfect for you :)

Comment: Join can cause records multiplication, exists not.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting comments. Will definitely check this suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this using `Dynamic query`. This will have good performance when compared to `JOIN/Exists` options

```
DECLARE @sql     NVARCHAR(max)='',
        @IsAdmin BIT = 1

SET @sql = '
SELECT
    ID,
    DepartmentID,
    FileName
FROM
    Document D
    ' + CASE WHEN @IsAdmin = 'false' THEN ' where exists (select 1 from  AllowedDepartmentList AD where D.DepartmentID = AD.ID ) ' ELSE '' END

--PRINT @sql 

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Dynamically framed query when `@IsAdmin = 0`

```
SELECT ID,
       DepartmentID,
       FileName
FROM   Document D
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   AllowedDepartmentList AD
               WHERE  D.DepartmentID = AD.ID)
```

Dynamically framed query when `@IsAdmin = 0`

```
SELECT ID,
       DepartmentID,
       FileName
FROM   Document D
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query would help you

```
SELECT  ID
        ,DepartmentID
        ,FileName
FROM    Document
        LEFT JOIN   AllowedDepartmentList ON DepartmentID = AllowedDepartmentList.ID
WHERE   @isAdmin = 1
    OR  ( @isAdmin = 0 AND AllowedDepartmentList.ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

add an AllowedDepartmentList.ID of like -1 for admin
pass a null or -1 for @adminID

```
ON isnull(@adminID, DepartmentID) = AllowedDepartmentList.ID
```

An OR (or @IsAdmin = 'true' ) is not efficient and this also just returns 1

Comment: This going to kill any index present on `DepartmentID`

Comment: @Prdp So, I assume AllowedDepartmentList.ID is a PK.  It is no worse than an EXISTS with less code.